# Chef Provisioning - How to use 'chef_server' attribute

Tags: ruby, automation, chef-infra, chef-provisioning

I am writing a [Chef provisioning recipe](https://docs.chef.io/provisioning.html) to deploy a number of VMs in our vCenter, using [vSphere driver](https://github.com/CenturyLinkCloud/chef-provisioning-vsphere) for chef provisioning.

As far as I understand `machine` and `batch_machine` resources have a `chef_server` attribute, however there is not much documentation about how this must be used or how it impacts, further than indicating it must be a ruby hash.

Anyone has used this attribute before? Can I use it to use our Chef Server for bootstrapping or provide our cookbooks? Anyone could provide some documentation or manual about how to use this?

Comment: I'm on mobile so you're getting the short version of my disclaimer, but just beware we do not recommend new users use chef-provisioning anymore as it is no longer under significant development. See https://coderanger.net/provisioning for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you but I set the chef server url outside the machine/machine_batch resource.  Something like this:

```
with_chef_server 'https://api.chef.io/organizations/my_org',
  :client_name => Chef::Config[:node_name],
  :signing_key_filename => Chef::Config[:client_key]
```

I found this info on https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning#pointing-boxes-at-chef-servers
The Chef::Config settings come from knife.rb file.  All my instances in a chef provision run talk to same chef server so I don't bother setting chef_server on machine resource.  I did make the chef server url an attribute so I can change it by loading a different environment file when I provision.